# Neighborhoods of a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E \subset R^n$ be closed, consider $O_k=\{x : \text{dist} (x, E) < \frac{1}{k}\}$. Then one can prove $E=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty O_k$. Further using continuity of the Lebesgue measure from above it follows that if $E$ is bounded (i.e. compact) then
$$|E|=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{|O_k|}$$

What is a counterexample of this property? I.e. find $E$ closed and unbounded so that the above equality is false? Thank you.

Comment: You can't have tried **anything** to solve this yourself. The only way you'll get this property for an unbounded $E$ is if $E$ has infinite measure, that's a very unimaginative example to use to find a counter example. Examining the proof for the property would also show where the property that $E$ is bounded is used.

Comment: I proved that $O_k$ is open, showed that $E=\bigcap O_k$ and that the equality $|E|=\lim |O_k|$ holds for $E$ compact... don't know why I was thinking that an unbounded set has measure $\infty$ and stuck on this... things like this happen when you study late at night... so sorry, but you are wrong !...

Comment: Then how did you use the fact that $E$ is bounded? You must have used that or your proof is wrong. Not that an unbounded set does not have to have infinite measure - in fact that would have saved the property.

Comment: when applying continuity of the measure from above you need $\exists k_0$ s. t. $|O_{k_0}| < \infty$ and this is where we use boundedness of $E$

Comment: I assume you mean that $|O_{k_0}|<\infty$? That would of course be a clue that for the property to hold then also $|E|$ had to be infinite. Finding counter examples is often done by examining the proof and check how the prerequisite is being used and build it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $E = \mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$, $E$ has measure zero while $O_k$ has infinite measure for all $k$.

(Indeed, take any closed, unbounded $E$ with finite measure. Then $O_k$ would have infinite measure)